# python pandas clean up empty rows after last row of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` like this:

```
     t1      t2     t3
0    a       b      c
1            b      
2 
3    
4    a       b      c
5            b      
6
7
```

I want to drop all values after index `5` because it has no values, but not index `2`,`3`. I will not know whether each column will have data or not.

All values are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [74]: df.iloc[:np.where(df.any(axis=1))[0][-1]+1]
Out[74]: 
   t1 t2 t3
10  a  b  c
11  b      
12         
13         
14  a  b  c
15  b
```

---

**Explanation**: First find which rows contain something other than empty strings:

```
In [37]: df.any(axis=1)
Out[37]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Find the location of the rows which are True:

```
In [71]: np.where(df.any(axis=1))
Out[71]: (array([0, 1, 4, 5]),)
```

Find the largest index (which will also be the last):

```
In [72]: np.where(df.any(axis=1))[0][-1]
Out[72]: 5
```

Then you can use `df.iloc` to select all rows up to and including the index with value 5.

Note that the first method I suggested is not as robust; if your dataframe has
an index with repeated values, then selecting the rows with `df.loc` is
problematic.

The new method is also a bit faster:

```
In [75]: %timeit df.iloc[:np.where(df.any(axis=1))[0][-1]+1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 203 µs per loop

In [76]: %timeit df.loc[:df.any(axis=1).cumsum().argmax()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 296 µs per loop
```

Comment: I could use that, but then I would need to get rid of all of the `NaN`s

Comment: the data in there is actually `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: and the empty ones are...?

Comment: it is a `<type 'str'>`. Sorry it was inherited.

Comment: actually, all the data is strings. I mispoke

Comment: sweet. worked! you would think this would be a function used regularly enough to be built in. But i guess not since i couldn't find anybody ask this question.

Comment: @jason: I changed the answer so as not to use `argmax` and `df.loc`. The new answer is more robust since it will properly handle DataFrames with repeated values in the index (as well as being a bit faster).

Comment: does `axis=1` mean looking at column `t1`? what if there is data in column `t2` like in my question? If that is the case, then need to loop through all of the `axis`?

Comment: Loosely speaking, `axis=0` run up and down each column, `axis=1` run across each row. So `df.any(axis=1)` tells Pandas to test if any item *in a row* is `True`.